# how do I get the following postgres queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: tableA and tableB. TableA has a field idA and tableB has a record idB and idBPtrA where idBptrA is a pointer to tableA (one of the idA).

I want, using postgres, to select records from a TableA that have the minimal number of records in tableB.

Something like:

```
select idA,idB,count(idBPtrA) as c 
from tableA,tableB 
group by idBPtrA 
where idA=idB order by c
```

This of course doesn't work and gives me an error, but I think it should be very similar to that... Any ideas?

Comment: What if the minimal number is 0?

Comment: That's fine, then it should choose it. @Gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the query that you want:

```
select a.idA, count(b.idB) as c
from tableA a left join
     tableB b
     on a.idA = b.idptrA
group by a.idA 
order by c;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases and qualify column names (especially if you are learning SQL).
- Learn and use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.